# Session Reset For Each Performance Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing, performance-testing

Using the example from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html#examples (1.2.1):

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'rails/performance_test_help'

class PostPerformanceTest < ActionDispatch::PerformanceTest
  def setup
    # Application requires logged-in user
    login_as(:lifo)
  end

  def test_homepage
    get '/dashboard'
  end

  def test_creating_new_post
    post '/posts', :post => { :body => 'lifo is fooling you' }
  end
end
```

Per the documentation, it says `setup` is called once per test, but when I run a test like the example, the session is maintained, and the next `setup` call uses the old session.  I used `reset!`, to clear the session in the setup.

Is that correct?  Do I also need to do the same thing in integration tests?  Why in the world is the session maintained?  Maybe I am missing something, like if there is a technique to see if logged/session exists?

Comment: the code behind `login_as` will most likely be asked for

Comment: The example from Rails Guides did not include one, so maybe that included a check to see if already logged in.